# DateTime in not working in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

From my database I am trying to fetch all records after a particular date. For this I am using the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM Events_tbl 
WHERE lastupdated > '07-18-2011' and Venue=8
```

This particular piece of code is working in my localhost. But when I upload to server it is not returning anything. Could someone help please?

I am really stuck.

In my SQL Server database the datetime value is

```
2011-07-19 19:37:50.727
```

I am using pipeten server in UK. I am working on asp.net c#

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the server holds dates that are after July 18th 2011?

Comment: Most likely to the collation your SQLServer is running with, you should specify the format of your datetime explicitly using convert: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928.aspx instead of letting SQLServer guess...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the ISO dateformat (YYYYMMDD) it is safe across all languages

```
SELECT * from Events_tbl where lastupdated > '20110718' and Venue=8
```

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you don't use a text format for your query in the first place - use a [parameterized query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) and specify the parameter value as a `DateTime`. That way you don't need to worry about formatting at all, and you keep your code away from your data.

There's no reason for you to perform a conversion either to or from text here - so don't. Keep the values in their most appropriate data type.

(This goes for all data values, by the way - and parameterized queries also help to protect you from SQL injection attacks.)

Comment: +1 Even if the dirty little secret of MySQL is that it turns all  parameterized queries into text in the .NET drivers :)

Answer (score 1):

The date in the where clause is in US date format but your server is in UK. So you need to swap the month and date in the clause. In UK, it's dd/mm/yyyy not mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Or better yet: use the **ISO-8601** format (`YYYYMMDD`) which is **independent** of what your server's locale and regional settings are.....

Answer (score 0):

Most probabbly your local machine localization is different from servers one, also look on request you make by using string litterals. Is your column in **varchar** format, or in **DateTime** format?

By the way working with date time values always use special operands/functions. Like:

[Msdn: DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx)

Regards.